# C# ExcelPackage set cell type as number

Tags: c#, excelpackage

I am using c# .net.
I am creating a new excel file from scratch.
Some of the cells contain text and some of the cells contain number.
How can I set using C# ExcelPackage a cell's type as number?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
// Get the entire column you want (in this example column A)
var range = someWorkSheet.get_Range("A:A");  
// Set the format to numbers
range.NumberFormat = "0";
```

(If you want to set it as text instead, then `range.NumberFormat = "@";`)